# Unity and ASP.NET WebForms - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container, webforms

Does anyone have any good examples of how to make Unity 1.2 or 2.0 work with ASP.NET WebForms?

I thought I had this figured out, but evidently I'm missing something.  Now I'm getting the error; "No parameterless constructor defined for this object".  I remember getting this error a couple years ago, I and just don't remember what I did.

Obviously Unity isn't working as it should because somewhere along the way I've forgotten something.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some of my code:

Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

using PIA35.Unity;

namespace PIA35.Web
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IUnityContainer container = Application.GetContainer();
            PIA35.Web.IoC.Bootstrapper.Configure(container);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my httpModules section of the web.config file:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="UnityHttpModule" type="PIA35.Unity.UnityHttpModule, PIA35.Unity"/>
</httpModules>
```

Here's the code for my IoC bootstrapper class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

using PIA35.Services.Interfaces;
using PIA35.Services;
using PIA35.DataObjects.Interfaces;
using PIA35.DataObjects.SqlServer;

namespace PIA35.Web.IoC
{
    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Configure(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container
                .RegisterType<ICategoryService, CategoryService>()
                .RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>()
                .RegisterType<IOrderService, OrderService>()
                .RegisterType<IOrderDetailService, OrderDetailService>()
                .RegisterType<IProductService, ProductService>()
                .RegisterType<ICategoryDao, SqlServerCategoryDao>()
                .RegisterType<ICustomerDao, SqlServerCustomerDao>()
                .RegisterType<IOrderDao, SqlServerOrderDao>()
                .RegisterType<IOrderDetailDao, SqlServerOrderDetailDao>()
                .RegisterType<IProductDao, SqlServerProductDao>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the HttpApplicationStateExtensions.cs file.

```
using System.Web;

using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace PIA35.Unity
{
    public static class HttpApplicationStateExtensions
    {
        private const string GlobalContainerKey = "GlobalUnityContainerKey";

        public static IUnityContainer GetContainer(this HttpApplicationState application)
        {
            application.Lock();
            try
            {
                IUnityContainer container = application[GlobalContainerKey] as IUnityContainer;
                if (container == null)
                {
                    container = new UnityContainer();
                    application[GlobalContainerKey] = container;
                }
                return container;
            }
            finally
            {
                application.UnLock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my UnityHttpModule.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace PIA35.Unity
{
    public class UnityHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        #region IHttpModule Members

        ///
        ///Initializes a module and prepares it to handle requests.
        ///
        ///
        ///An  
        ///that provides access to the methods, properties, 
        ///and events common to all application objects within an ASP.NET application 
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += OnPreRequestHandlerExecute;
        }

        ///
        ///Disposes of the resources (other than memory) 
        ///used by the module that implements .
        ///
        ///
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        #endregion

        private void OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IHttpHandler handler = HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            HttpContext.Current.Application.GetContainer().BuildUp(handler.GetType(), handler);

            // User Controls are ready to be built up after the page initialization is complete
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            if (page != null)
            {
                page.InitComplete += OnPageInitComplete;
            }
        }

        // Get the controls in the page's control tree excluding the page itself
        private IEnumerable GetControlTree(Control root)
        {
            foreach (Control child in root.Controls)
            {
                yield return child;
                foreach (Control c in GetControlTree(child))
                {
                    yield return c;
                }
            }
        }

        // Build up each control in the page's control tree
        private void OnPageInitComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page page = (Page)sender;
            IUnityContainer container = HttpContext.Current.Application.GetContainer();
            foreach (Control c in GetControlTree(page))
            {
                container.BuildUp(c.GetType(), c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of one of my service classes.

```
namespace PIA35.Services
{
    public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
    {

        #region Dependency Injection

        private ICategoryDao categoryDao;

        public CategoryService(ICategoryDao CategoryDao)
        {
            this.categoryDao = CategoryDao;
        }

        #endregion


        #region ICategoryService Members

        public List GetAll()
        {
            return categoryDao.GetAll().ToList();
        }

        public Category GetById(int CategoryId)
        {
            return categoryDao.GetById(CategoryId);
        }

        public void Add(Category model)
        {
            categoryDao.Insert(model);
        }

        public void Update(Category model)
        {
            categoryDao.Update(model);
        }

        public void Delete(Category model)
        {
            categoryDao.Delete(model);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out that this actually works.  I'm just using it wrong.  I'm trying to bind a GridView to an ObjectDataSource which points to the CategoryService class.  It doesn't seem like the ObjectDataSource control can take an interface.  So I need to do this in code.  Oh well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see it has already been answered but just thought I would point out that you are synchronising all the calls to GetContainer with your locking pattern. A call to Application.Lock() actually takes out a write lock on the applicationState which is a singleton object in your web application and you will see issues if you want to scale this.

To tidy this up you could do a double checked lock. like this:

```
    public static IUnityContainer GetContainer(this HttpApplicationState application)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = application[GlobalContainerKey] as IUnityContainer;
        if (container == null)
        {
            application.Lock();
            try
            {
                container = application[GlobalContainerKey] as IUnityContainer;
                if (container == null)
                {
                    container = new UnityContainer();
                    application[GlobalContainerKey] = container;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                application.UnLock();
            }
        }
        return container;
    }
```

I would also like to point out a neat pattern that we have used to ensure Controls and Pages have their Dependencies built up.  We basically have a Generic PageBase and Generic ControlBase that all our pages and controls inherit from.  I will just go into the pagebase as an example:

```
public abstract class SitePageBase<T> : SitePageBase where T : SitePageBase<T>
{
    protected override void OnInit( EventArgs e )
    {
        BuildUpDerived();
        base.OnInit( e );
    }

    protected void BuildUpDerived()
    {
        ContainerProvider.Container.BuildUp( this as T );
    }
}
```

Then in our Pages we can simply derive from Generic base and it will look after the build up.

```
public partial class Default : SitePageBase<Default>
{
        [Dependency]
        public IContentService ContentService { get; set; }

        protected override void OnPreRender( EventArgs e )
        {
            this.label.Text = ContentService.GetContent("labelText");
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

The ObjectDataSource can take an interface, but not with the wizard. You can use the wizard to create the ObjectDataSource tag then edit it and turn the TypeName attribute value into your interface name.

Then, you need to instruct the ObjectDataSource how to create the object. The way i'm using is to handle the OnObjectCreating event, so in the code behind I have:

```
[Dependency]
public IMyService Service { get; set; }

protected void OnObjectCreating(...)
{
   e.ObjectInstance = Service;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a working project a while back and I started a new project and getting the same problem.
Make some comparison and took me a while. But I remembered that you need to initialise
it in the global.asax.

```
Bootstrapper.Initialise(); // Missing in the global.asax
```