# ASP.NET/C# - Dependency Injection (Unity) and Server.Execute - dependencies are not injected

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to execute another page in the project I'm working on using Server.Execute (I need the exact HTML response to store this on the server in a file, which is run from the same user context).

```
    // small test case
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter twrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        Server.Execute("../MCC/Default.aspx", twrite, true);
        lbl1.Text = twrite.ToString();
    }
```

However, if I try to run any of our pages that use Dependency Injection, the dependencies are not injected, and NullReferenceExceptions are the result.

```
    // These are all "null" - but they should have been injected
    [Dependency]
    public IRadGridSettingManager RadGridSettingManager { get; set; }
    [Dependency]
    public IMCCManager MCCManager { get; set; }
    [Dependency]
    public IMCCItemManager MCCItemManager { get; set; }
```

How can I make sure these dependencies are loaded in run-time? (I'm guessing I need to change something in the page load to force injection when it has not been done automatically (is null); but I have no idea how to go about doing this)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663380/unity-and-asp-net-webforms-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-objec it might help

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! I've figured it out - turns out the project was using a HTTP handler to bind the IUnityController to the ASP.NET pages. Since Server.Execute skips the HTTP handler, no dependencies were injected.

Comment: (click the up arrow next to my comment!!! ;-) )

Comment: (i don't see any arrows - think my rep's too low =( )